# Elliptic curve isomorphic with direct product of $S^1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elliptic-curves

I am having trouble with the following property of elliptic curve:

Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ with two generators. Show that the group $\mathbb{C}/\Gamma$ is isomorphic to $S^1\oplus S^1$.

I suspect the approach would be the same as showing $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $S^1$, but that the best I could try.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: One way to start would be to think geometrically -- take the complex plane, and see if you can find a minimal cell such that every complex number is congruent to some location in the cell. What's the shape of the cell? Is there any congruence relation between its sides?

Comment: @jwimberley I do know about the existence of the fundamental parallelotope, but that would help me here?

Comment: Sure, it would help. Also think about the orbit of a point in that parallelotope when acted by one of the generators vs the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b$ a $\Bbb Z$-basis of $\Gamma$, now consider the $\Bbb R$-linear automorphism $A:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ given by $A(1)=a,A(i)=b$, $A$ has the property that it maps the lattice $\Lambda:=\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z i$ to $\Gamma$ by construction. Thus $A$ induces an isomorphism $\Bbb C/\Gamma \cong \Bbb C/\Lambda$.

Now the map $f:\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb R/\Bbb Z \to \Bbb C/\Lambda,(x,y) \mapsto \overline{x+iy}$ is an isomorphism, so we get $\Bbb C/\Lambda \cong S^1 \oplus S^1$ as $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z \cong S^1$.

Another way to finish the argument would be to note that generally if $G_1,G_2$ are groups with normal subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ respectively, then $(G_1 \times G_2) / (H_1\times H_2) \cong (G_1/H_1) \times (G_2/H_2)$